# Remove empty lines (&nbsp;) when author updates their post

Tags: tinymce, the-content, save-post, characters, line-breaks

Whenever adding an empty line between paragraphs using TinyMCE, the `&nbsp;` character entity is added.

How can I strip the content of all instances of this character whenever an author updates their post (`save_post`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, hooking into `content_save_pre`:

```
function remove_empty_lines( $content ){

  // replace empty lines
  $content = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/", "", $content);

  return $content;
}
add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_empty_lines');
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked your solution but it might happen to be that the " " is legit or intended in some part of the content further down in the content structure. The problem - at least for me - only occurs for the unnecessary and annoying extra lines at the beginning of the content.
So I decided to extend your solution by only removing the extra "nonBreakingSpaces" at the very beginning of the text before any further tags occur:

```
function remove_empty_lines( $content ){

  // replace empty lines
$contentArr = explode('<',$content,2);
if (count($contentArr)==2) // only then  
{ 
    $contentArr[0] = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/", "", $contentArr[0]);
    $content = $contentArr[0].'<'.$contentArr[1]; 
}  
return $content;
}
add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_empty_lines');
```